# ASP.NET MVC application randomly logs out users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, asp.net-identity

I have ASP.NET MVC application which has been working for almost 2 years. I upgraded it to ASP.NET Identity and after that, it randomly logs out user.

I have tried all possible solutions found on web without success. I have also machine key configuration in web.config.

I suspect on IIS Application Pool recycling, but I can not reproduce issue on local IIS.

Can someone help me to resolve issue or to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but can not find a solution. Did you find any?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your Startup.Auth class for ExpireTimeSpan, that is used by .Net identity to log a user out after a certain period of time.  May look like this:

```
ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
```

Possibly that is what is causing you to randomly logout, however this would have been setup by someone at some point.  That's the only thing I can suggest from the information provided.

Comment: Already have this as well as sliding expiration set to true in Startup.Auth